# SSMS Renaming objects in query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Using SSMS is there an easy way to rename objects throughout the query besides using Find and Replace.

Example

```
SELECT
    R.RateId,
    R.RateTypeId,
    E.emp_lname 
FROM
    Rates R LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbl_employees E ON R.CreatedByEmployeeId = E.emp_pk
```

I would like an easy way to change the alias for 'R' and 'E' throughout the entire query. Obviously this one is simple to fix but I could not find an easy way to "Refactor -> Rename" for when the query is long and has many sub queries.

Find and Replace doesn't work for me when I have sub queries with the same Aliases like in this example.

```
SELECT
    R.RateId,
    R.RateTypeId,
    E.emp_lname,
    SubQuery.CreationDate

FROM
    Rates R LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbl_employees E ON R.CreatedByEmployeeId = E.emp_pk LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (   --Arbitrary sub query for example purposes
        SELECT *
        FROM Rates R
        WHERE R.CreationDate > '2012-01-01'

    )SubQuery ON R.RateId = SubQuery.RateId
```

Comment: you want to refer to the table by a different alias halfway through the query?  what are you trying to do???

Comment: Change the Alias throughout the entire query.

Comment: Find and replace `R.` with `X.` ?  Then the only place left to fix it is the actual table name.  What is wrong with find and replace? Are you stuck with subquries that reuse the same alias?

Comment: If I have sub queries that use the same Alias as outer queries. I am working with ugly tsql (IMO) that does this a lot.

Comment: I don't know any other way besides selecting the biggest chunks of code you have that don't repeat aliases and doing a find/replace in the selection.  That is a royal PITA though, sorry man.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a manual editing situation.